# Using admob and revmob within one app allowed?

Tags: admob, revmob

Id like to know if admob has some policy or something that forbids using other ad networks besides admob within the same app. For example, I would like to use revmob for a full banner at app start and then use admob for small banners in the app.

Comment: Have you read through the terms of service?

Answer (score 3):

Admob forbids you to use more than one ad in a single screen. So at one time there can be only one ad banner. If you're using admob for banner ads and revmob for interstitial,then you're fine. I've multiple games in iOS and Android store, which uses the same method.
Just don't show more than one ad simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if any ad network forbids this, but it's a common practice among the developers.
Most of the apps that show ads use more than one ad network.

Answer (score 0):

Admob has no such policy, nor should it, or any other ad network. If you are using AdMob you may as well be using their mediation offering which will let you request ads from other networks.